# python web programming in Eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, web-applications, pydev

Is there any video tutorial or book from where I can learn python web programming in django platform in Eclipse(pydev).Please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist to start with Eclipse, [this series is a good start point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1STjuSTKcU), I guess..

Answer (score 1):

Try [The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html), or start with the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score 0):

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html should get you started. If you're new to eclipse, I would find a tutorial on that first as they have a lot of their own lingo.